# Taffy Basic login prompt appears

Tags: coldfusion, taffy

I'm trying to find what causes the Basic login dialog to prompt when accessing a protected endpoint. 
we are behind SSL and using Taffy REST framework.

The http basic login I'm referring is like this https://www.httpwatch.com/httpgallery/authentication/#showExample10
(click on the "Display Image" button)

Our onTaffyRequest code

```
function onTaffyRequest(verb, cfc, requestArguments, mimeExt, headers, methodMetadata, matchedURI){

            //get username and password
            structAuth = structnew();

            structAuth = getBasicAuthCredentials();

            structAuth.authenticated = false;
            local.status = "forbidden";



            /*<!--- Get request from ColdFusion page contenxt. --->*/
            objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest(); 
            /*<!--- Get requested URL from request object. --->*/
            requestArguments.strUrl = objRequest.GetRequestUrl().Append(
                "?" & objRequest.GetQueryString()
            ).ToString();


            /* CATCH NO BASIC auth*/            
            //if username is blank return false
            if (structAuth.username is ""){
                return representationOf( local.status ).withStatus(401);
            }

            //check invalid password
            if(structAuth.password is ""){
                return representationOf( local.status ).withStatus(401);
            }       


            return true;
        }
```

Is the `objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest();`   making the login prompt appear?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the `objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest()` bits, does it still give you the basic authentication prompt?

I suspect you probably have an `.htaccess` file in the directory where your API is located that is requesting basic auth via Apache (or, if using IIS, you have basic auth required through IIS) which is presenting the login prompt.

That's a server level dialog and unlikely to be something you can conjure up through code.

Comment: I did try to remove the objRequest = GetPageContext().GetRequest() and the prompt didn't appear. I'm puzzled how GetPageContext().GetRequest() is able to bring the Basic login prompt